# What is the correct date format for this date-as-a-string?

Tags: ios, swift, date, dateformatter

The back end is providing me with this date-as-a-string: `2021-09-10T12:57:01.671Z`

I need to convert that string to a `Date` using the iOS `DateFormatter`; and to do so I need to set the formatter's `dateFormat` property.

I have tried all sorts of combinations, with no luck. Specifically I am struggling with the `.671Z` part.

What is the correct date format to use?

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"

Comment: `ISO8601DateFormatter` + `[.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]` `formatOptions` should do the trick...

Comment: @RajaKishan - No, that is not correct. The `Z` should not be in quotes. Properly configuring date formatters for ISO 8601/RFC 3339 dates is surprisingly complicated, which is why one should use `ISO8601DateFormatter`.

Comment: That format is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need **"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"** as date format

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
     
       
guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: self) else {
 // fallback if date is not in correct format
    return nil
}
```

Comment: The `Z` should not be in quotes. If you're going to do this, I'd suggest `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"` and, if the formatter is also going to be used to prepare string representations for the server, set `dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)`. Frankly, as Larme said, `ISO8601DateFormatter` is the better solution.